# Different conditions on data measurement for ml

Tags: data-transformation, dataset, measurement, measure-theory, mixed-type-data

Is it possible to train a prediction model (on my case classifier with four classes) between data taken on different conditions?

To be more specific I have two data sets and for my task I am allowed to train an ML model with the first data set which contains measurements for 500 samples  and validate/test it with the second data set which contains the exact same samples but with measurements taken on different conditions (eg: The measurements are taken with a spectograph on the outdoors and indoors)

Comment: Thats my first Question, are the tags and the format  relevant?